# Unable to capture random id in view pager

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments, android-viewpager, simplecursoradapter

I have implemented view pager with cursor pager adapter as in it is fetching the data in random order from `SQLite` and displaying the same in pager's fragment. It is working absolutely fine. Now I want to give user an option to mark these quotes as favourite. My approach is to set a flag against quote_id in database and have achieved this too successfully but the problem is whenever i swipe right or left and wants to unfavorite the 'favorite one' quote then it is not working because id on swipe is incorrect as in if i am 3rd quote then id of 1st quote is getting displayed. Need your help in resolving the same.

**ItemPagerFragment.java**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_pager, container, false);

    // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter in app.
    mPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(-5, null, this);
    adapter = new CursorPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), null);
    mPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

    CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), 
            DataProvider.CONTENT_URI_DATA, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null, 
            "RANDOM()");

    return loader;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {

    adapter.swapCursor(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

    adapter.swapCursor(null);
}   

/**
 * A simple pager adapter.
 */
private class CursorPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private Cursor mCursor;

    public CursorPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Cursor c) {
        super(fm);
        mCursor = c;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
            Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
            arguments.putLong(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, mCursor.getLong(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DataProvider.COL_ID)));
            ItemDetailFragment fragment = new ItemDetailFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(arguments);
            return fragment;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (mCursor != null) {
            return mCursor.getCount();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public void swapCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        mCursor = cursor;
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}    

}
```

**ItemDetailFragment.java**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments().containsKey(ARG_ITEM_ID)) {
        id = getArguments().getLong(ARG_ITEM_ID);

}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_detail, container, false);
    FrameLayout rlB =(FrameLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.layout);

        Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(DataProvider.CONTENT_URI_DATA, id);
        Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contentUri, null, null, null, "RANDOM()");

        if (c != null) {
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                final int favFlag = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DataProvider.COL_FAVFLAG));
                final ImageButton favButton = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonFav);
            if(favFlag ==1)
            {
                favButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.addtofav1);
            }
                else
                {   
                    favButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.addtofav);
                }
                favButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

                       @Override
                       public void onClick(View v) {
                           if(favFlag == 0)
                           {
                               favButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.addtofav1);
                               Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(DataProvider.CONTENT_URI_DATA, id);
                                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                                cv.put("favorite", "1");
                                int count = getActivity().getContentResolver().update(contentUri, cv, null,null);
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                        "Added To Favorite " + count,
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                           }
                           else
                           {
                               favButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.addtofav);
                                  //update the object  
                               Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(DataProvider.CONTENT_URI_DATA, id);
                                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                                cv.put("favorite", "0");
                                int count = getActivity().getContentResolver().update(contentUri, cv, null,null);
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                        "Removed From Favorite" + count,
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                           }
                       }}); 
            }
            c.close();
        }
    }

    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Please help me out by suggesting a solution.

Comment: Even a suggestion will do. Please help me out.